# How to add haptic feedback to a scrollable widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How does one add haptic feedback to a scrollable widget? Specifically, in these two cases:

- When the scrollable widget is currently being scrolled.
- When the scrollable widget reaches the start/end edge of the scrollable area.

The first case should have light haptic feedback frequently emitted throughout the duration of the event, and the second case should have a more heavy haptic feedback emitted once.

**This is bad because it doesn't have haptic feedback, but it is the desired layout:**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.redAccent),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.deepOrange),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.purple),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The desired outcome is very similar to how several Apple-based scroll views work. For example, the Apple Watch emits the same haptic pattern desired when you scroll with it.

Having haptic feedback would make the scrolling experience very pleasant for users, and also would help with accessibility issues in applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this problem, and just created a package for it: https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable.

To allow your scrollable widget to emit haptic feedback, you can wrap it in the `ScrollHaptics` widget. By default, this will work, however, you can also change the properties of the widget to your liking.

**This is how the provided example looks with `ScrollHaptics` added:**

```
ScrollHaptics( // <----- Added here!
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.redAccent),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.deepOrange),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.purple),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Here's another version, with some properties changed for the sake of example:**

```
ScrollHaptics( // <----- Added here, with example properties changed below.
      bubbleUpScrollNotifications: false,
      heavyHapticsAtEdgeEnabled: true,
      hapticEffectAtEdge: HapticType.medium,
      hapticEffectDuringScroll: HapticType.light,
      distancebetweenHapticEffectsDuringScroll: 55,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.redAccent),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.deepOrange),
            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.purple),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```